"He was my father?" vs. "He is my father?"
I've been thinking about this for a long time now, and still haven't been able to come up with a logical explanation.
Which is more correct,
[1] "He was my father." Or "He is my father?"
[2] "He was born on April 20, 1920." Or "He is born on April 20, 1920."?

To be born is always past unless you are being literary and uses all present tenses (historoical present). Person 1: Who is that man? Person 2: He was my father. [he is deceased]. You have two different questions here. The present can be used in narration.

If he's alive, he IS your father.
If he's dead, he WAS your father.
However, as long as you are alive you would always say "I am his son". When you are dead, other people will he say "he was the son of...".

On the subject of declaring birth dates, birth is an event that occurred in the past, so we say "he was born on...". However, as that date in history is also a fixed event, we can say "his birth date is...".

Whilst I agree with your answer, I think confusion arises because the biological relationship between you and your father hasn't been changed by his death. "Was" can imply that, somehow, he is no longer your father. Or am I just overthinking this?

Surely I am always my father's son? And my mother's come to that. @PeterJennings - I believe you are not overthinking this.

I agree with this - he was alive at the time of writing David Faber (politician) Wikipedia: He is the grandson of the late former Conservative Prime Minister Harold Macmillan (1894–1986). but I think this is wrong - he was dead at the time of writing - LOS ANGELES (AP) ... Keough died from a self-inflicted gunshot wound Sunday in Calabasas, California. He is the grandson of the late Elvis Presley.

Can I mention that my father knew Lloyd George?

@MichaelHarvey, Can I mention that my father shook hands with Franklin D. Roosevelt?

…and that my kids saw Jimmy Carter at a book signing?

It's a song... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd_George_Knew_My_Father_(song)

It depends on whether you are using historical present or just writing/speaking normally.

@PeterJennings I think that IS the confusion I've tried to address. One's relationship to other people doesn't change by their death, but one's living status determines how we speak of them.

@lambie you mean also depends. Well, that's a given. If you find something written in the present tense while someone was alive but read it retrospectively after they died it would be different than if it had been written now. How do you feel this comment enhances the answer?

It enhances the answer because it explains an unusual usage of to be born in the present. It's the kind of thing others here might point out.

This question is not as simple as it might appear, because there are two elements woven together: first, is that person related to me, and second, is he alive or dead?
If my father is alive, then we will say, "He is my father", using the present tense.
But if my father is dead, then actually either tense is correct, depending on what information I wish to communicate. If I wish to confirm the family relationship and not talk about my father's death, then "He is my father" is still a correct sentence. But if I say, "He was my father", I am revealing both facts about him at the same time.
So in part it depends on what information you want to disclose.

You don't understand the difference between someone who is alive and someone who has passed away?

My best friend is Joanna Smith
My best friend was Joanna Smith

If there were no  context, a reader could interpret this as Joanna no longer being my friend but my opening sentence removes the ambiguity and sets the context. Do we use is or was  for a person (it needn't be a parent) living today or who died at some point in the past?
On the other hand, I understand the OP's confusion about dates of birth because in Italian we literally say “She is born the 20 april of 1992” whereas in English the date/event is considered to be a single episode fixed in the past, so the copula(r) verb, be, is in the past tense.
She was born on April 20, 1992
But if you're talking about birthdays that is quite different. Birthdays happen every year during a person's life so the present simple is used for a person who is living, the year can be omitted
Joanna's birthday is on April 20. She is (now) 32 years old.
If Joanna passed away (died) then the verb will be in the past
Joanna's birthday was on April 20. She was 27 when she died.

I think this confuses matters because someone can cease to be your friend but still be alive. The OP's question is about a familial relationship.

@Astralbee and Joanna was 27 when she died is still alive? The question is not just about a father (or mother) being alive or dead but fair enough. The downvote is justified.

Mine was downvoted when your answer came in, without comment. If you can tell me what's wrong with mine that would be appreciated.

@Astralbee I didn't downvote. I would ask the author of any comment or observation that was even slightly critical.
